# a good way to constrain sum of different instances

Tags: specman, e

I have a struct (mystruct_s for example) under which there are several same type structs (packet_s for example) in different hierarchies.

```
struct packet_s {
   size:uint;
   active:bool;
};

struct mystruct_s {
   // packet struct paths:
   // p
   // q.p
   // w.p
};
```

I would like to generate an instance of mystruct_s and enforce that the sum of the sizes of all active packets would be less than 1K.

```
var s : mystruct_s;
gen s keeping {
     // it.p.size (if it.p.active) + it.q.p.size (if it.q.p.active) + it.w.p.size (if it.w.p.active) < 1024 ;
};
```

Is there a simple way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please name the title as a question; also, your question is definitely too broad--try refocusing your question to a smaller scope.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward solution would be using ternary and plus to sum the sizes if active :

```
var s : mystruct_s;
gen s keeping {
    (it.p.active ? it.p.size : 0) + (it.q.p.active ? it.q.p.size : 0) + (it.w.p.active ? it.w.p.size : 0) < 1024 ;
};
```

If you using Specman 14.1 (or above) you can use generative literal list and sum to write the following constraint:

```
var s : mystruct_s;
gen s keeping {
    {it.p; it.q.p; it.w.p}.sum(it.active ? it.size : 0)) < 1024 ;
};
```

Using generative literal list will also give you better distribution on the sizes.

If you using Specman 14.2 (or above) you can use conditional sum instead of sum with ternary:

```
var s : mystruct_s;
gen s keeping {
    {it.p; it.q.p; it.w.p}.sum(it.size, it.active) < 1024 ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of packet_s with a single list.
Then use list pseudo method .sum constraint

Answer (score 0):

Try (not sure if this will work):

extend my_struct {
    keep {p.size*p.active.as_a(bit),w.p.size*w.p.active.as_a(bit),...}.sum(it) < 1024;
}

Answer (score -1):

```
Keep %{mystruct.p.size, mystruct.q.p, ...}.count(it) < 1K
```

Comment: How should that work? %{} concatenates all values; count() expects all boolean as argument.